# Using Flow union types for Redux actions

Tags: redux, flowtype

Following the style of [this Facebook app sample](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/actions/types.js) using Redux and Flow together, I made an action type in this manner:

```
type Action =
  | { type: 'ADD_FILES', files: Array<{ id: number, file: File }> }
  | { type: 'HANDLE_IMAGE_PUBLISHED', id: number, name: string }
  | { type: 'SET_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS', id: number, progress: number }
;
```

But I've found that when I try to process my actions with a reducer, Flow complains if I try to access the `name` or `progress` properties, saying "Property not found in object type".

That is, in my reducer, if I check that `action.type === 'HANDLE_IMAGE_PUBLISHED'` and then access `action.name`, Flow complains. And the same thing goes for for accessing `action.progress` property when `action.type === 'SET_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS'`. Both these property accesses should be legit under their respective circumstances, as far as I can tell, but Flow complains.

Yet for some reason it's OK for me to access `action.id` anywhere, even though one of the types in my union doesn't specify an `id` property. I'm very confused.

[Here is a live demo in the Flow REPL](https://flow.org/try/#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-o2zY0fhbBgQmxFiFB4bWgpcGIcheFoe6GGsFhpGfrhqEgYR7F2Z5lGHq5IVtgJPhcawIm8uJoDyVG3KiXyGlEf22nIOWEpStAuBvv2CXfqV1SIJpQA). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a case of a type refinement invalidation:

https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations

Because you are using the value in a callback, Flow pessimistically assumes that you could have re-assigned `action` before the callback runs (it does not know that the `map` callback is called immediately). It also does not do the analysis to see that there is no place, in fact, that you re-assign it.

All that's needed is to pull the `action` out as a `const`:

```
export default (state: Array<ImageRecordModel> = [], action_: Action): Array<ImageRecordModel> => {
  const action = action_;
```

([tryflow link](https://flow.org/try/#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-qomlIY0mMzmSxGkjzolAYVwcmwvQNVeroHTbbTPXT63C6eoGBlMqOrFW3duOb4D0HzZbiO8M+r3bn8609kczlc0kl0ELS-nNl0+kMBGwchQu+r1VttvPojb6flivPRuFLf0hdAIw+31+-yBILBkLQrC8KVvOtb1r0D4oL2VD9jKYjUK6WoeuOvrTtYkAph2MjphIoAAIR8AICEam6bC4awObgQ24iIZq7qsNGy7Ub0frLrebYkUhDE3tW+56AYm4GDu6F8XYfhOFkQnbmeomiL4a5BCEYQRNIACMvGiGiSrYem2maRcZgnJUvF1NOl4vtWb5FoSJK-uSlI0nSAQMkyLIVtOLFpLgCrQX2A5cfRbCobm7FiJhqaRhRBFEbRpHIawFFUSgdY0YFZEekxYEpRBoXsa2nF0Rlw5yT4EmsEpvKqRGoY4dyyl8qZWUXralmiBKUrQLgoEzl5UFMdUiBmUAA))

You may also want to consider enabling const params in your `.flowconfig`. This does basically what you expect: treats all params as `const`:

```
[options]
experimental.const_params=true
```

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. I guess it would make sense to use `experimental.const_params=true` as I'm using ESLint's `no-param-reassign` rule too.