# redux reducer flow not inferring type

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, flowtype

I ran into a flow error while doing essentially the basic redux-reducer example from [flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/redux/#toc-typing-redux-reducers).

Error from flow added to the code here: on the `REMOVE` switch case: `action` is not resolved to the correct type.

If i hover over `payload` in vscode, in the `ADD` case it displays it as `AddAction`, but on `REMOVE` case it is displayed as a union of all the actions, i.e. `Action`.

What am i missing or understanding wrong? Flow should deduct the correct type down from the `Actions` union to the only possible type(s) inside `if` and `switch`.

```
// @flow
const initialState = [];

type Item = { id: number, data: string };
type State = Item[];

type AddAction = {
  type: 'ADD',
  payload: Item
};

type RemoveAction = {
  type: 'REMOVE',
  payload: { id: number }
};

type ClearAction = {
  type: 'CLEAR'
};

type Action = AddAction | RemoveAction | ClearAction;

const reducer: (State, Action) => State = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD': {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    }

    case 'REMOVE': {
      return state.filter(t => t.id !== action.payload.id);
                                               ^ property `payload`. Property not found in
    }

    case 'CLEAR': {
      return [];
    }

    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

- code on [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAluntngIbQDK2J2ApqALygDaAugNzLYCeADnQJK0Atg1ABvfABMAXKHQBXIQCMaAJwA0oSdRKycqggHNQAXw7c+oStTqNBNIaw6ILdAIKTJblMQyixiKCgrrIA5G4AIhGh6oGgPCRccCQyoPZCiGacvHQASg6wAG403r7o-nEhoKG5AKIAsgDyAGq1MXEJSbApshJ4qQrKaqaZzq6gAMLQNCSqpXh+jAFBVaETADK1brmho9mW84ugHl4+C+UAPqD5QkUlZ35XUzNzD+jOaFi4qjSS8ihqWQACmstE0h3QAEoGAA+KxUWiiIE4GyiAhEUgUBE0TQkN7Q+hw5agTDwIgoAAWoCBeLKADpXNDiUEUCRMHRwlFQr04kEgj9sPJVOUmHSxSiwaBaec6Z1kpJ2LyRkrWezqnUmq1ueIlfyaILhSTsXTIHhoLRVEDcITgnT+qAAIT0RjSjCyxLyu2SSEcPnKv2qjkbLY7Hl+vUGkWKv0mZB+yQ0SAkeTm6S66mu9CyBw8bg+9MCoXlCU0X0jLKIGgADx4sFUuATSZT31+-zUziAA)
- [another try-flow repl](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN6phgDU2+AXGAOSHMA0VtAJgIYa8mlatRrc8eHEK4jaAOwCuAWyaKlAIzwAnGWAC+XAwdTBgYbgEsoUbXjkZz-XmADOGLQoDGGBVryZcAgAhUgouOkCmZiCOcL4BaVkaC24mNy0LOQBzQ1RjUzA5OEcBAPwwAGFQ4Vp6PCiK2OM6sAAFOBcXC3UYPAAVQJdQ4gAfMBCxioBudE84OTcwKwBRAA9eJRxe0IAKTJwFDCZ2zu7egfwXAEpSAD4w6iswPbkDjAA6FpJvljYbmuoBX2hyWQ0yNi0fm4YF4Q2IsNcEjkYHmYHUcAwGDgSjAWLgMHUvC0YAQAAs7GBPL4XHBiajmMCMMxdHMFvi8O94FkXm93vFeHyJDh3mpaGAAExXGbUAyPKDPRmfQKkH7RZj-XRA14gixguQQqEwoYhBEuJEo5HozHY3FwfGE4lkilUrQ0unIhnapks+Y03qcuDcgBEKSYQbFiv57xSUtycoVXqV5W+ZGYAA11Q8RFq3qC2h0uj1+oM0SCimBYIgwNotLSAPw+hYOVahRVkrDRlyfUm6kUY968OTvGu06X6PKzX0OFwICwYTyktYbLYEMg8w7HAtnYuXG4ke41Gdzhfrj51DWyTywgisZiJbNmRl58E1vDQhGEXTUVl+jlc098k4gqSCKyi0JKY6yOofi8AA1pB46XteLAxPegKPl6z76q+77Gl+lK+uyAbBikYDhjQSyJlGMYIbK450fhQA) where i do essentially the same thing and type inferring works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the problem was the use of `action` inside `Array.filter` arrow function:

If i replace the `REMOVE` case contents with

```
case 'REMOVE': {
  const id = action.payload.id;
  return state.filter(t => t.id !== id);
}
```

the errors go away.

I guess flow cannot infer the type inside the arrow function. Would be interesting to know why.

edit: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376241/using-flow-union-types-for-redux-actions)

So, flow invalidates the union refinement because it assumes filter() might be doing side effects to reducer parameter `action` ([docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#refinement-invalidations)). Storing the action or payload in a const before using fixes this.